using graphics hardware in an ssh -X session
I recently had problems installing the correct video driver on my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 (as per topic: Ubuntu 20.04 and UHD graphics Intel N100 processor). After many attempts I managed to install the drive and use the integrated graphics hardware correctly. Now I have the following problem:
When I run the RVIZ program directly on the computer (Ubuntu Desktop 20.04) I notice that the program is loaded using the Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-N) graphics hardware and then the RVIZ program works perfectly.
.
.
[INFO] [1717458732.168128181]: OpenGL device: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-N)
[INFO] [1717458732.168154587]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6) limited to GLSL 1.4 on Mesa system

However, when I remotely access (from a notebook with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04) the machine through "ssh -X server_ip" I notice that when running the same RVIZ program it uses llvmpipe instead of Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL- N):
.
.
[ INFO] [1717458579.136272211]: OpenGL device: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits) 
[ INFO] [1717458579.136313623]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5) limited to GLSL 1.4 on Mesa system.

Is there any way to use the remote machine's graphical hardware even when accessed by ssh -X?

Does the method you are using for remote access support a GUI interface?

I'm connecting from a notebook with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04, I'm opening the shell and typing ssh -X server_ip. I don't know if I understood your question well.

Your question only talks about Ubuntu 20.04. Please update he question with all the correct details. An answer is only as good as the info given.

updated information. Do you need any more specific data?
